# LINQ Group By on DateTime

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a table with a column with different smalldatetime value.
I would separate results by Month and Year, something like this:

JANUARY 2016: ....

....

AUGUST 2017: ....

SEPTEMBER 2017: ...

...

I have done something like this:

```
var query = db.Table.GroupBy(q => q.date.Value.Month);
```

but it separate only by month and not also by Year, so I can't discern for example AUGUST 2016 from AUGUST 2017.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Try `.GroupBy(q => new {Month = q.date.Value.Month, Year = q.date.Value.Year})`...

Comment: Do you want to preserve the original date within the group, or just the month/year.

Answer (score 1):

This should serve your purpose:

```
    var groupedDates = dates.GroupBy(d => new { d.Date.Year, d.Date.Month }).SelectMany(g => g.ToList());
```